# Infinite ObjectAnimator with interpolator... How to accelerate only the initial start?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, interpolation, objectanimator

I have a object animator with infinite repeat mode. I want to accelerate it only the first time it starts... not every time it is repeating itself

How can this be achieved?

my code:

```
universeMovement1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(universeImageView, "x", 0, sw);  
        universeMovement1.setDuration(UNIVERSE_MOVEMENT_TIME);
        universeMovement1.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        universeMovement1.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
        universeMovement1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
```

Answer (score 11):

Add a listener to your animation with the method onAnimationRepeat and set the interpolator back to LinearInterpolator, or whatever you want. Hence when it repeats it won't accelerate anymore.

```
animation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```